# Adding multiple DNS to CSR with Openssl via command prompt

Tags: openssl, command-prompt, csr

I need help understanding how to create a CSR with multiple DNS in it. I am creating csr using windows command prompt

Originally I use

```
Openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout -test.key -out test.csr
```

Which create csr with 1 common name.

I search online and the code I being trying are

```
openssl genrsa -out test.key
openssl req -new -key test.key -out test.csr -config csr.conf
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in test.csr -signkey test.key -out test.crt -extensions req_ext -extfile csr.conf
```

But, I'm sure it's obvious to y'all, the -config command from second line doesn't work. Saying it can't find the following file config file.

I'm very new to all of this. And I am doing csr because it's part of my internship. Doesn't help that the no one knows how to do it. I've tried searching online for half a day and I still can't find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Subject field in both a CSR and an X.509 cert can only effectively contain one DNS name in CommonName, at least as commonly used for TLS, the <strike>artist</strike>protocol formerly known as SSL. Technically RDNs can have multiple values, but the specification provides that only the first will be used and all others ignored. If this is certificate is for something other than TLS, it *may* allow other combinations of name attributes, in which case you should refer to the relevant specification(s) for that protocol or application.
2. For TLS, and some other uses, you *can* instead put multiple DNS names in the [SubjectAlternativeName extension (SAN)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.6) as described for TLS in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-2.3) and HTTPS specifically in [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1).
3. It is possible to put a SAN extension (or technically *requested* extension) in a CSR. On properly designed systems with OpenSSL this is described in the man page(s), but Windows doesn't do man pages, so you need to look at the online version [for `req(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/req.html#CONFIGURATION-FILE-FORMAT) which describes the configuration file in general and links to [`x509v3_config(5)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man5/x509v3_config.html#Subject-Alternative-Name) which describes SAN specifically.

   Addition: for version 1.1.1 (which was current in 2020) up, you *can* instead specify requested extensions in a CSR using `-addext`, described earlier on the `req(1)` man page. (But don't use *both* `-addext` and the config file -- it creates an invalid request!)
4. But since you're using `openssl x509 -req` to create the cert from the CSR, this is completely useless because `x509 -req` does not use any extension(s) from the CSR. Instead if you want a certificate with SAN containing DNS names, you need to create the *certificate* with this extension, not the CSR. The simplest way to do this is to use `req` with both `-new` and `-x509` which effectively combines your second and third steps:

   ```
     openssl req -new -key test.key -x509 -days 365 -config $file -out test.crt
   ```

   In this case the config file, as described on the man page linked above, can specify both the Subject name *and* the extensions (using the `x509_extensions` item) which can include SAN, and/or commandline options `-subj` and `-addext` respectively can do so. You can also have it include the first step (`genrsa`) as in your first example:

   ```
    openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout test.key -x509 -days 365 -config $file -out test.crt
   ```

   Update: for 3.0.0 released in 2021 up, `x509 -req` has option `-copy_extensions`, which *does* work with method #3. OTOH this approach of creating the cert directly with `req -new -x509` also works and is simpler overall.